# ¿Cómo puedo detectar un archivo que está almacenado en una USB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente para poder leer una USB por medio del lenguaje de programación Python 3.6. Consiste en detectar si en una USB existe un archivo x.dat el cual es un posible virus, y debe anunciar que fue detectado en tiempo real, es decir, si yo ingreso la USB al puerto del ordenador, el programa deberá anunciar si existe o no dicho archivo.

Agradezco el apoyo para guiarme en la detección de la USB sin importar en cual puerto ingrese la USB. Inicialmente estoy trabajando en windows pero el programa debería ser multiplataforma con distros de linux.

```
import sys #Librería que permite identificar cual plataforma se encuentra utilizando el programa
plataforma = sys.platform #sys.platform almacena la información de la plataforma que se está usando
import os.path
import os

print(plataforma)
archivo = "Istealyourinfo.dat"
if(plataforma == "linux"):
    print("Estoy usando linux")
    os.listdir("E://")
elif(plataforma == "win32"):
    print("Estoy usando windows 32 bits")
    directorio = ["E:\\","F:\\","G:\\","H:\\","I:\\","J:\\"]
    path = ''
    i = 0
    while(path != archivo):
      print("entro")
      if(i>5):
        break
      else:
        for root, _, files in (os.walk(directorio[i])):
           print("Entro3")
           if archivo in files:
             print("Entro4")
             path = os.path.join(root,archivo)
             break
           else:
             print("No existe")
             break
      i = i+1
    print("Se detecto el archivo: ", path)
else:
  print("No uso plataformas populares")
```

Comment: Muy buenas Giovanny, ¿podrías indicarnos que has investigado o intentado para que podamos ponernos en contexto y así poder ayudarte mas fácilmente? Te recomiendo que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Ya agregué lo que pude comprender para poder extraer la información del dispositivo. Pero aún así, no encuentro la manera de detectar la introducción de la USB

Comment: Hola Giovanny. **Pulsa en [edit]** para añadir a la pregunta el problema actual que te encuentras. Entiendo que solo seria la deteccion del USB y que el reconocimiento del archivo `x.dat` ya estaría?  Piensa que los comentarios deberian poder borrarse sin que afecte a la pregunta, por lo que **la pregunta tiene que tener toda la informacion necesaria**. Un saludo